# When to create a new build directory for yocto?

Tags: yocto

I'm maintaining a Yocto build system to produce these outputs:

```
1. ARM SOC 1
  1). board 1 image
  2). board 2 image
  3). SDK for i686
  4). SDK for x86_64
2. ARM SOC 2
  1). board 3 image
  2). board 4 image
  3). SDK for i686
  4). SDK for x86_64
```

Now I don't know the right way to create build directories for these builds.
The simplest way I think is creating one build directory for each of these builds.
But it wast resource for boards with the same SOC which can share cross toolchain.
So the right way is creating one build directory for each SOC, then bitbake each output's
recipe, right?

I am also not sure if I can put the SDK and board image in the same build directory.
Because once I build a board's image after creating its SDK, I add gdbserver to it,
but the build fail without really building the gdbserver package. So I guess the 
board image build is confused by the SDK build state.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be able to use one build-directory for each SoC, without any problem. There's no issue in building images and the SDK in the same build directory (if this gives you some issue, please let us know on the mailing list).

Quite likely, you should also be able to share the build directory between both SoC's (though there is a sligthly large risk of getting issues here). And frankly, it might not be worth the risk.

If you decide to keep the two SoC's separate, you should at least be able to share the downloads directory and the sstate-cache between the two SoC's.